# How to deduce information about center of group if only order of centraliser is given?

Tags: group-theory

> Suppose centraliser of group of element has order 4 . Then what information can we deduct about center

I know that $Z(G)\subset Z(x)$ where $|Z(x)|=4$

Any group of order 4 is abelian $|Z(G)|=1,2,4$.

Now I got some examples of with above property

Like In $D_4$ or $Q_8$ $|Z(G)|=2$

In $Z_4$ ,$|Z(G)|=4$

But I could not able to find example with $|Z(G)|=1|
$ and $|Z(x)=4|$

What else info can we deduce?

Any Help will be appreciated

Edit:

As Derek says $A_4$ has $Z(G)=1$ there is (12)(43) which has 4 centraliser element

Comment: Try $G = A_4$ with $x$ an element of order $2$.

Comment: I got now .But What else info can we deduct

Comment: You have proved that $|Z(G)|=1,2,4$ are all possible. What else could there be to say?

Comment: You can say that if $|Z(G)| = 4$, then $G = Z(G)$.

Comment: If MathLover in the second line means strict inclusion (⊂), then x∉Z(G), so |Z(G)|=1 or |Z(G)|=2.